# Best way to check multiple strings in an if statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement

What is the cleanest way of checking multiple strings in an if statement, I want to be able to check to see if the users country is one that uses the euro which I will put in the ("???") .Because this works.

```
if (usercountry.equals("FRA") || usercountry.equals("FRA")|| 
    usercountry.equals("FRA") || usercountry.equals("FRA") || 
    usercountry.equals("FRA") || usercountry.equals("FRA") || 
    usercountry.equals("FRA") || usercountry.equals("FRA") ||
    usercountry.equals("FRA")) {
        costpermile = costpermile*1.42;   //(costpermile=£)   (costpermile*1.42=Euros)
}
```

but it looks awful

BTW im not checking France over and over again its still prototype code and so I haven't entered every euro country without checking if there was a better way first.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. This: `usercountry.equals("FRA")||usercountry.equals("FRA")` is the same as just `usercountry.equals("FRA")` (OR'ing something with itself doesn't affect its value). So in each one of those ors, is the _variable_ supposed to change, or the string literal? That is, do you want `usercountry.equals("FRA") || usercountry.equals("BEL")`, or `usercountry.equals("FRA") || somethingelse.equals("FRA")`? Those are different answers.

Comment: Put all your required matches into a `List` and use `contains`.  You could maintain the `List` as a `static` resource if it does not change (greatly).

Comment: Why not use a [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html). Just leave the body of all cases blank, with no `break`, except for the last matching case, and provide definition :-)

Comment: A `Set` rather than a `List`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Regex**

```
if (usercountry.matches("FRA|GER|ITA"))
{
    costpermile = costpermile*1.42; 
}
```

**2. Add countries to a data structure (Set) and check**

```
Set<String> eurocountries= new HashSet<String>();
eurocountries.add("FRA");eurocountries.add("GER");eurocountries.add("ITA");

if (eurocountries.contains(usercountry))
{
    costpermile = costpermile*1.42; 
}
```

Note: I think its the regex method you're looking for

Comment: I like your regex version better.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 7 or later you can use a switch statement on a String like so

```
switch(userCountry)
{
    case "FRA":
        costpermile = costpermile*1.42;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Then you can just add whatever additional cases you need.

Comment: Not disagreeing, but with something like 26+ required matches, that would be quite a long switch ;)

Comment: Totally agreed. Too many cases and it would be a little unwieldly

Comment: the `break` statement in the `default` branch isn't necessary :) *in your case*

Answer (score 1):

You could store the strings in an array and then iterate over it like this:

```
String[] str = {"EN", "FRA", "GER"};
for (String s : str) {
    if (usercountry.equals(s)) {
        // Match: do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO- `List#contains` would require list code, just saying ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Are you sure, you wanted to reply to my answer? ;)

Comment: It's not a criticism to your answer per-say, but I'd just prefer `List#contains` over an enhanced loop, but that's just me ;)

Comment: Ah ok. Now, I got it (the relation between your comment and my answer was not clear to me). And yes, you might be right :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you could use a `Set` for storing the country codes:

```
private static final Set<String> EURO_COUNTRIES 
    = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("FRA", "ESP", "ITA", "GER" /*etc..*/));
```

Then in your code, you can check the country in the following way:

```
String userCountry = Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country();

if (EURO_COUNTRIES.contains(userCountry)) {
    // do something
}
```

However, a better long-term solution might be creating a rich `enum`, especially if you need to attach more logic with these country codes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
String euroCountries []  = {"FRA", "DEU", ...}

public boolean isEuroCountry(String userCountry){
  for(String country : euroCountries){
    if(usercountry.equals(country)){
         return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could append a prefix for each country that belongs to a particular continent then just check for that token.
For e.g. in Europe countries:

- E_FRA
- E_BEL
- E_GER
- ...

would be **E**

Asian countries:

- A_CHN
- A_MLY
- A_PHL
- ...

would be **A**, and so on.

```
if ( userCountry.startsWith("E") ) {
     // Europe countries
} else
if ( userCountry.startsWith("A") ) {
    // Asian countries
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String countries[] = {"FRA", "GER", "ENG"} // declaration of the countries you want to list.

// function to calculate the cost per mile 
public double calculateCostPerMile(String userCountry){
    double costPerMile;
    for(String country: countries){
        if(country.equals(userCountry)){
            return costPerMile*1.42; // return value

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One could also use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsAny(CharSequence cs, CharSequence... searchCharSequences)`